# undefined method `to_key' for #<Class:0x17a6408> -rails-3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, methods, undefined

I am experiencing problems with undefined method `to_key' for, on a form for polymorphic upload.

This is the form partial:

```
<%= form_for [@parent, Upload], :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|  %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :document %><br />
    <%= f.file_field :document %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Upload"%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is the controller:

```
class UploadsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_parent

  respond_to :html, :js

  def index
    @uploads = @parent.uploads.all unless @uploads.blank?
    respond_with([@parent, @uploads])
  end

  def new
    @upload = @parent.uploads.new unless @uploads.blank?
  end

  def show
    @upload = @parent.upload.find(params[:upload_id])
  end

  def create
    # Associate the correct MIME type for the file since Flash will change it
    if  params[:Filedata]
      @upload.document = params[:Filedata]
      @upload.content_type = MIME::Types.type_for(@upload.original_filename).to_s
      @upload = @parent.uploads.build(params[:upload])
      if @upload.save
        flash[:notice] = "suceessfully saved upload"
        redirect_to [@parent, :uploads]
      else
        render :action => 'new'
      end
    end
  end

  def edit
    @upload = Upload.where(params[:id])
  end
  private


  def find_parent
    classes ||= []
    params.each do |name ,value|
      if name =~ /(.*?)_id/
        @parent =  classes << $1.pluralize.classify.constantize.find(value)
      end
    end
    return unless classes.blank?
  end
end
```

If i change

```
<%= form_for [@parent, Upload], :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for [parent, Upload], :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
```

I get a new error: undefined local variable or method `parent' for #<#:0x21a30e0>

This is the error trace:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `to_key' for #<Class:0x2205e88>):
1: <%= render :partial => "uploads/uploadify" %>
2: 
3: <%= form_for [@parent, Upload], :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|  %>
4: 
5: 
6:  <div class="field">
```

The "uploads/uploadify" partial is in this gist: https://gist.github.com/911635

Any pointers will be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I can see, your `form_for` should be something along the lines of

```
<%= form_for [@parent, @upload], :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
```

as I'm assuming your upload object is nested within another object, similar to the following:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :uploads
end
```

What form_for does when passed an array like this is construct the relevant path based on the class of the given objects and whether they are new records.

In your case, you create a new upload object in the new action of your controller, so form_for will inspect the array, get the class and id of @parent, then get the class and id of @upload. However, because @upload has no id, it will POST to `/parent_class/parent_id/upload` instead of PUTting to `parent_class/parent_id/upload/upload_id`.

Let me know if that doesn't work and we'll figure it out further :)

-- EDIT - after comments --

This means that one of @parent or @upload is nil. To check, you can put the following in your view

```
<%= debug @parent %>
```

and the same for @upload and see which is nil. However, I'm guessing that @upload is nil, because of this line in your controller:

```
# UploadsController#new
@upload = @parent.uploads.new unless @uploads.blank?
```

specifically the `unless @uploads.blank?` part. Unless you initialize it in the ApplicationController, @uploads is always nil, which means @uploads.blank? will always be true, which in turn means @upload will never be initialized. Change the line to read

```
@upload = @parent.uploads.new
```

and the problem will hopefully be resolved. The same is true of the other methods where you have used `unless @uploads.blank?`.

On a semi-related note, in UploadsController#find_parent, you have this line

```
classes ||= []
```

because the variable is local to the find_parent method, you can be assured that it is not initialized, and should rather write classes = [].

Also, you have this line of code

```
return unless classes.blank?
```

right before the end of the method. Did you add that in so that you return from the method once @parent has been initialized? If so, that line should be inside the each block.

Further, since classes isn't used outside of the method, why define it at all? The code could read as follows and still have the same behaviour

```
def find_parent
  params.each do |name ,value|
    @parent = $1.pluralize.classify.constantize.find(value) if name =~ /(.*?)_id/
    return if @parent
  end
end
```

Amongst other things, you'll see that this does a few things:

1. Avoids initializing a variable that is not needed.
2. Inlines the if statement, which helps readability for single line conditionals
3. Changes use of `unless variable.blank` to `if variable`. Unless your variable is a boolean, this accomplishes the same thing, but reduces the cognitive load, as the former is essentially a double negative which your brain has to parse.

-- EDIT - from email exchange about the issue --

You are correct - `if @parent` will return true if parent is initialized. As I mentioned on SO however, the exception to this is if @parent is initialized and set to false. Essentially what it means is that in Ruby, all values except nil and false are considered true. When an instance variable has not been initialized, it's default value is nil, which is why that line of code works. Does that make sense?

> In terms of setting @parent in each action that renders form in the UsersController, which of these is the correct way to do this on the index action. I have tried all 3 but got errors

Remember that both @parent and @upload must be instances of ActiveRecord (AR) objects. In the first case, you set @parent to User.all, which is an array of AR objects, which will not work. Also, you try to call @parent.uploads before @parent is initialized, which will give a no method error. However, even if you were to swap the two lines around, you are calling @parent.uploads when parent is an array. Remember that the uploads method is defined on individual AR objects, and not on an array of them. Since all three of your implementations of index do similar things, the above caveats apply to all of them in various forms.

> ## users_controller.rb
>
> def index
>    @upload = @parent.uploads
>    @parent = @user = User.all
>    end
>
> ```
>   or
> ```
>
> def index
>      # @user =   @parent.user.all
>       @parent = @user = User.all
>    end
>
> ```
>   or
> ```
>
> def index
>      @parent = @upload = @parent.uploads
>      @users =  User.all
>    end

I'll quickly walk you through the changes I made. Before I start, I should explain that this

```
<%= render "partial_name", :variable1 => a_variable, :variable2 => another_variable %>
```

is equivalent to doing this

```
<%= render :partial => "partial_name", :locals => {:variable1 => a_variable, :variable2 => another_variable} %>
```

and is just a shorter (and somewhat cleaner) way of rendering. Likewise, in a controller, you can do

```
render "new"
```

instead of

```
render :action => "new"
```

You can read more about this at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html Now on to the code.

```
#app/views/users/_form.html.erb
<%= render :partial => "uploads/uploadify" %>

<%= form_for [parent, upload], :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|  %>


 <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :document %><br />
    <%= f.file_field :document %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Upload"%>
  </div>
<%end%>
```

On the uploads form, you'll see that I changed @parent and @upload to parent and upload. This means you need to pass the variables in when you render the form instead of the form looking for instance variable set by the controller. You'll see that this allows us to do the following:

```
#app/views/users/index.html.erb
<h1>Users</h1>
<table>
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to user.email %></td>
      <td><%= render 'uploads/form', :parent => user, :upload => user.uploads.new %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Add an upload form for each user in UsersController#index. You'll notice that because we now explicitly pass in parent and upload, we can have multiple upload forms on the same page. This is a much cleaner and more extensible approach to embedding partials, as it becomes immediately obvious what parent and upload are being set to. With the instance variable approach, people unfamiliar with the code base might struggle to determine where @parent and @upload are being set, etc.

```
#app/views/users/show.html.erb
<div>
  <% @user.email %>
  <h3 id="photos_count"><%= pluralize(@user.uploads.size, "Photo")%></h3>
  <div id="uploads">
    <%= image_tag @user.upload.document.url(:small)%>
    <em>on <%= @user.upload.created_at.strftime('%b %d, %Y at %H:%M') %></em>
  </div>

  <h3>Upload a Photo</h3>
  <%= render "upload/form", :parent => @user, :upload => user.uploads.new %>
</div>
```

This is similar to the changes above, where we pass in the parent and upload objects.

```
 #config/routes.rb
 Uploader::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users do
    resources :uploads
  end

  devise_for :users

  resources :posts do
    resources :uploads
  end

  root :to => 'users#index'
end
```

You'll see that I removed uploads as a top level resources in the routes. This is because uploads requires a parent of some sort, and so cannot be top level.

```
#app/views/uploads/new.html.erb
<%= render 'form', :parent => @parent, :upload => @upload %>
```

I made the same changes as above, passing parent and upload through explicitly. You'll obviously need to do this wherever you render the form.

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 respond_to :html, :js

  def index
    @users =  User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      redirect_to users_path
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    respond_with(@user)
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @user.destroy
    respond_with(@user)
  end
end
```

I've removed any mention of @parent from the user controller, as we pass it through explicitly.

Hopefully that all makes sense. You can extrapolate from these examples and pass through the parent and upload object wherever you want to render an upload form.

Comment: Looks like you're right. `upload` is not a method, but object :)

Comment: @luke thanks for your time and guidance. Yes in the route, the upload object is nested in another object. I have implemented the change but it now returns **undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class**. Here is a brief excerpt of the error message: **Extracted source (around line #3): **. This is line 3 **<%= form_for [@parent, @upload], :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|  %>**. Thanks.

Comment: @luke thanks, i will make this changes shortly and get back to you. I had added 'unless @uploads.blank?' because it was giving a different nil class error which only that addition resolved. But i will remove it now and folow your changes. I will be back shortly. Thanks.

Comment: @luke I have used the irb from within ruby-debug and @upload, @uploads and @parent are all nil. Furthermore, at @parent.uploads or @parent.uploads.new gives **nomethoderror: undefined method 'uplods' for nil class**. But the same error **undefined method model_name still comes up after the implemetation of your guide.

Comment: @luke in addition to the above, i thought i should explain why i added 'classes' to the method, though it is removed as suggested, but explaining will help you see if it applies to my context._I added classes to the method because i thought it will make it easier to implement polymorphic association with 2 level nesting structure. Eg I have comment nested in post and i want to be able to attach uploads to both model. Secondly i want to move that method into lib folder, so i can call it in all polymorphic models. Eg the upload model and that comment model you helped me fixed before._

Comment: I decided to initialize the instance variable @parent, with **def initialize
  @parent = [ ]
end**. So that @parent instance variable is no more nil, but @upload is still nil so the old error is still being returned. I added similar initialization for @upload to upload.rb but the old error is still being thrown.

Comment: Would you like to send me a copy of the project and I can take a look?

Comment: @luke thanks for the detailed answer and clear explanations that helped me resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

[@parent, Upload] => [@parent, :upload]

```
<%= form_for [@parent, :upload], :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|  %>
```

**UPD**

You should change places `:upload` and `@parent`

```
<%= form_for [:upload, @parent], :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|  %>
```

Comment: @floor Thanks for your suggestion. I have implemented that change but it now gives me this new error and that was the only change i made from what was posted earlier on:                                                                        **undefined method `model_name' for Symbol:Class**

Comment: @flOOr thanks for your time. I have implemented the new update by swapping their places but the error was still returned. That is **undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class** before it was **Symbol:Class**. Thanks again

Comment: that means that you didn't initialized `@parent` object in your controller action. In another words: @parent is nil.

Comment: Thanks. I added an initialize method it still gave error. I then tried using accessor method for parent but the error is still thrown. Your guidance has been helpful.